# "had" permissible?

Tags: grammaticality, indirect-speech

*Grammar for CAE and Proficiency, Hewings
Backdrop: Stephen shares his experience after a job interview.*

I admitted __________  (have problems) in the early stages of the work. [his PhD research]

The answers are as follows (I have an issue with the last one)
having problems 
having had problems 
to having had problems 
to them that I had had problems
**to them that I had problems**

Clearly, early stages of the work are in the past at the moment of speaking and so past perfect should be used in reported speech. Why past simple then?

Comment: Do you mean that all the options are considered to be valid insertions into the sentence (which they are apart from the duplication of "admitted" with the first three) and that you can't understand why the last one is valid?

Comment: I think the last two aren’t valid simply because it adds *to them*. I would understand by the presentation of the question that only a conjugation of “have problems” Is allowed.  Otherwise, if we can arbitrarily add extra words, why not: “I admitted John to the program because he was having problems in the early stages ...”

Comment: @Jim "I admitted to them that I had (or had had) problems ..." sounds perfectly normal to me if the speaker is describing an interview with the panel evaluating his PHD. It's the extra 'admitted' in the first three that I don't like. If you put the first one into the sentence as  it stands you get "I admitted admitted having problems in the early stages..." The fact that the first three phrases are different in that respect from the first two is sloppy at best.

Comment: @BoldBen - I agree that *admitted* shouldn’t be in the choices. It is sloppy.

Comment: Well, Stephen is sharing his experience after a job interview. That's all we know. Students are supposed to be able to figure out the correct answer. And yes,  BoldBen, I am not sure why "to them that I had problems" is correct. And yes, all the options are considered to be valid insertions into the sentence by Hewings, the author of the manual

Comment: @Nimitta If all of them are considered valid then I don't see what Hewings is asking. It might be a touch clearer with a bit more context but it's all very strange to me.

Comment: The Perfect versions (2,3,4) all strongly imply the problems were over and done with by the time speaker admitted to their (prior) existence. The other two *could* be used with that sense, but they'd more naturally be taken to mean speaker *still* had those problems at time of admitting to them. Other than that, they're just alternative phrasings, where the specific ***stylistic choice*** made has no real significance.

Comment: I'd not use that particular variant, but the past perfect is often avoided as wordy when sequentiality is obvious or immaterial.

Comment: @BoldBen It wasn't a multiple question task. :-) The task was to fill in the gaps in a bunch of sentences<br> I admitted __________ (have problems) in the early stages of the work. [his PhD research]<br>

Comment: @FumbleFingers  My point is "early stages" imply that we are talking  about the past, otherwise he would not refer to them as "early". If the problems are "in the past" at the moment of speaking, then "he admitted that he HAD problems in the early stages of the work" is not a viable answer.

INDIRECT: I admitted to them that I had problems in the early stages of the work. 

DIRECT:"I have problems in the early stages of the work" - does not make much sense.

DIRECT: "I had problems in the early stages of the work" - makes sense, but then Past Perfect should be used when reported.

Comment: @Nimitta: I think you may be misunderstanding the exact details of how Past Perfect is used. So far as I'm concerned, the Simple Past version *He admitted that he HAD problems in the early stages of the work* is a perfectly acceptable alternative to the Perfect version *(...that he HAD HAD problems)*. Just because it's a context where you ***can*** use the Perfect doesn't mean you ***must***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I found it. Swan explains the rule in "Practical English Usage"; "Past perfect tenses are not always used, especially if the time relationships are clear without a change from past to past perfect." The example sentences: "I told you John (had) phoned this morning, didn't I?" and "We were glad to hear you (had) enjoyed your trip to Denmark."

Comment: @Nimitta: Well found! Also note that this "tense simplification" is an *ongoing trend* in English. Swan's exact text probably hasn't changed with each new edition, but if it *had*, it might have shifted from *perfect tenses are **occasionally** not used* through ***...not always** used* to ***...often** not used* as we move through the decades. The general principle today should be *Only use the Perfect if you **have** to,* rather than *Use the Perfect whenever you **can***.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers Thank you! Yes, I noticed that. :-) I am a bit worried that Cambridge might not keep up with the recent trends (I mean Cambridge exams). Hence, in writing I would rather err on the side of caution and stick to orthodox perfect tenses.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don’t know the entire context or the person’s story except for the fact that it happened in past, any tense that is past is correct.

Simple, perfect, continuous, perfect continuous, past perfect, it all makes sense.